# Alternative proof for $\Bbb R\ni x\mapsto e^{ix}\in S^1$ Lipschitz condition with $K=1$?

Tags: analysis, alternative-proof, lipschitz-functions

> Alternative proof for $\Bbb R\ni x\mapsto e^{ix}\in S^1$ Lipschitz condition with $K=1$?

I need to prove that the function defined as

$${\rm cis}:\Bbb R\to S^1,\;x\mapsto e^{ix}$$

is Lipschitz with $K=1$. I can prove it with geometric reasoning, using basic facts about the cosine function, but it is supposed I must prove it just using the analytic definition of trigonometric functions like

$$\cos x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

and probably some bound as

$$|s-s_n|\le |x_{n+1}|$$

where $s$ is a convergent alternating series, $s_n$ is a partial sum and $x_n$ are the elements to add in the series.

---

I found that

$$\frac{|e^{ix}-e^{iy}|}{|x-y|}=\frac{|e^{iz}-1|}{|z|}=\frac{\sqrt{2(1-\cos z)}}{|z|}=\sqrt{2\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{z^{2k-1}}{(2k)!}}$$

where $z=x-y$, but I dont get something useful from here to prove the Lipschitz condition with $K=1$ for any $0\le z<2$.

---

I know too that ${\rm cis}$ is a (continuous and) surjective homomorphism between the groups $(\Bbb R,+)$ and $(S^1,\cdot)$, but I dont get any idea from here to prove that it is Lipschitz with $K=1$.

In this line of work I tried to think about the relation of Lipschitz condition and compactness, but anyway I need to prove that $K=1$ not only that the function is Lipschitz, what it is not clear from this approach.

Some hint or solution will be appreciated, thank you.

---

**UPDATE:**

If I show that

$$\frac{|e^{ix}-1|}{|x|}=\left|i\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(ix)^{k-1}}{k!}\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(ix)^k}{(k+1)!}\right|\le \left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}\right|=|e^{ix}|=1$$

Im done, but the last inequality is not as easy to prove from the power series as it seems.

Answer (score 2):

It follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus that if $x\leq y$ then
$$ e^{iy}-e^{ix}=i\int_x^ye^{it}\;dt$$
and therefore
$$ |e^{iy}-e^{ix}|=\Big|\int_x^ye^{it}\;dt\Big|\leq \int_x^y\;dt=y-x$$

Comment: The book dont covered this topic yet. I can use only analytic definition of trigonometric functions and closer topics.

Comment: You can use power series but not integration? That seems strange to me.

Comment: So you are not allowed to know that the line segment joining two points is the shortest path between them? (This follows from the triangle inequality and an integral, of course.) Surely nothing with power series is appropriate here.

Comment: @carmichael561 the book is _Analysis I_ of Amann and Escher, I dont reached derivatives neither.